# Max with other fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

Here is my query :

```
SELECT id, id_gamut, position from operation
```

It returns :

```
N°1)    id    id_gamut    position
        --------------------------
         1        19           1
         2        19           2
         3        19           3
         4        25           1
         5        25           2
         6        12           1
```

I need to group it by id_gamut with the max position to get a result like this :

```
N°2)    id    id_gamut    position
        --------------------------   
         3        19           3    
         5        25           2
         6        12           1
```

Then i tried something like this :

```
SELECT gamut, Max(position) from(
SELECT id, gamut, position from operation) as req
GROUP BY gamut
```

It works, but my problem is i really need to have the field 'id' in my query, but if i add it like this :

```
SELECT id, gamut, Max(position) from(
SELECT id, gamut, position from operation) as req
GROUP BY gamut,id
```

My group by is broken and i have a result like result N°1

How can i group by id_gamut with max position and having the 'id' field too ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
select top 1 with ties
    id
  , id_gamut
  , position
from operation
order by row_number() over (
  partition by id_gamut 
  order by position desc
)
```

Or using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
      partition by id_gamut 
      order by position desc
    )
  from operation
)
select 
    id
  , id_gamut
  , position
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Or as a subquery without the `cte`

```
select 
    id
  , id_gamut
  , position
from  (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
      partition by id_gamut 
      order by position desc
    )
  from operation
) s
where rn = 1
```

Or with [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
select distinct 
    x.id
  , o.id_gamut
  , x.position
from operation o
  cross apply (
    select top 1
        id
      , position
    from operation i
    where i.id_gamut = o.id_gamut
    order by position desc
    ) x
```

Or with [**`not exists()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.a) (This will return more than 1 row per `id_gamut` if there is more than one row with the same max position)

```
select *
from operation o
where not exists (
    select 1
    from operation i
    where i.id_gamut = o.id_gamut
     and i.position > o.position
    )
```

Or with [**`not exists()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.a) (Additional clause to return highest id in the event of multiple rows with the same max position)

```
select *
from operation o
where not exists (
    select 1
    from operation i
    where i.id_gamut = o.id_gamut
      and (i.position > o.position
           or (i.position = o.position and i.id > o.id)
          )
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/INV77202

Comment: top with ties comes in 2012? Or exist in 2008?

Comment: @SandipPatel Works fine with 2008

Answer (score 1):

Using ROW_NUMBER() inside Common Table Expression

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT id, id_gamut, position 
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_gamut ORDER BY position DESC) AS Rn   
   FROM operation
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MAX function and GROUP BY clause :

```
 SELECT  *
 FROM table1
 JOIN 
 (
   SELECT id_gamut,MAX(position) position
   GROUP BY  id_gamut
 ) A ON A.id_gamut = table1.id_gamut AND A.position = table1.position
```